# How to change all directive scope value from any one of directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

I have a directive which was repeatedly n times. I have click event action in every directive. Whenever I click, on click function, It change some scope variable names which defined in directive. But It wont change on all other directives? How to achieve this? I have my plunker here.[example](https://plnkr.co/edit/LXpcgYBHr7iFRJRjTOTs?p=preview)

html:

```
  <!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp" >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  this is 1st time: <div sampledirective></div>
  <br />
  this is 2nd time: <div sampledirective></div>
  <br />
  this is 3th time: <div sampledirective></div>
  <br />
  this is 4th time: <div sampledirective></div>
  <br />
  this is 5th time: <div sampledirective></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have rendered 'sampledirective' as 5 times in my view.

controller:

```
  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.bar ="original bar";
  $scope.term = "original term"
  $scope.temp={};
  $scope.callMethod = function (){
    $scope.term = "Changed term"
    $scope.bar = "Changed bar";
    $scope.temp.callMethod();
  }

});
```

I have created one object 'temp' in my controller.

directive:

```
app.directive('sampledirective', function($http) {
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope:true,
       replace: true,
       link:function(s,e,a){
         s.directive_scope="original directive_scope value";
         s.temp.callMethod = function(){

            s.directive_scope="Changed directive_scope value";
         }

       },
       template: '<div ><a ng-click="callMethod()">click_here</a> <span> <b>{{bar}}</b></span>   <span> <b>{{term}}</b></span>  <span> <b>{{directive_scope}}</b></span></div>'
  }

});
```

In my directive template I have 'temp.callMethod()' which is changed the scope variable value 'directive_scope= Changed directive_scope value'. But It was not reflected in other directives. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problem

Take a closer look at your directive definition, notice you put `scope:true` in there.

What it does is it tells Angular to create a new isolated scope for this particular instance of the directive inheriting it from the parent one.

So you are stuck with 5 directive instances all with their own scopes and when you assign directive_scope in one of them it will in no way reflect in the others. You can read more about directives and their scopes [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object)

#### Solution 1

You should define property in the parent scope and then pass it to the directive using two-way binding

Controller definition

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.directiveScope = null;
    $scope.temp = {};
    $scope.callMethod = function () {
        $scope.term = "Changed term"
        $scope.bar = "Changed bar";
        $scope.temp.callMethod();
    };
}]);
```

Directive definition

```
app.directive('sampleDirective', function () {
    return {
        ...
        scope: {
            temp: '=',
            callMethod: '&',
            directiveScope: '=' 
        },
        ...
    };
});
```

HTML

```
<div sample-directive temp="temp" call-method="callMethod()" directive-scope="directiveScope"></div>
```

**Be aware** that each directive instance will write it's own `temp.callMethod` function to the parent scope's `temp` property.

#### Solution 2

You should define a service that will store the shared values and inject it in the controller and the directive

Service definition

```
app.factory('sharedData', function () {
    return {
        directiveScope: null
    };
});
```

Controller definition

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'sharedData', function ($scope, sharedData) {
    ...
    $scope.callMethod = function () {
        $scope.term = "Changed term"
        $scope.bar = "Changed bar";
        sharedData.directiveScope = "Changed directive_scope value";
    }
}]);
```

Directive definition

```
app.directive('sampleDirective', ['sharedData', function (sharedData) {
    return {
        scope: {
            callMethod: '='
        },
        link: function ($scope, $element) {
            $scope.sharedData = sharedData;
        },
        template: '<div><a ng-click="callMethod()">click_here</a> <span> <b>{{bar}}</b></span>   <span> <b>{{term}}</b></span>  <span> <b>{{sharedData.directiveScope}}</b></span></div>'
    };
}]);
```

**Notice** that I changed the output in the template to `{{sharedData.directiveScope}}`

Comment: In Approach 1: scope.bar and scope.term (parent scope) and temp.callMethod is not accessible in directive template. see this-> https://plnkr.co/edit/9868kOs2IG7w2knbkd7X?p=preview @Dennis

Comment: In Approach 2: sharedData.directiveScope value is not updated across all directives. see this plunker-> https://plnkr.co/edit/M5AaKDmPZS0OV8RqUqlx?p=preview

Comment: I am passing different datas from controller also I am fetching different datas from http in each time the same directives is rendered. So, If I change scope , all directives will be shown same datas. plunker here. check this-> https://plnkr.co/edit/LXpcgYBHr7iFRJRjTOTs?p=preview

Comment: regarding Solution 1: my bad - forgot to add `callMethod` and `temp` to two-way binding. updated your plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/LeU7Gcbr7l4w21qrG4TE?p=preview). will update my answer now

Comment: I tried this plunker (third one). It does not updated all the directives. https://plnkr.co/edit/LXpcgYBHr7iFRJRjTOTs?p=preview Can you clarify this?@Dennis It was updated only the last directive.

Comment: I've updated my [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/LeU7Gcbr7l4w21qrG4TE?p=preview) to show you that it's working properly.

Comment: where is the data value which is passed from controller.  each directive will show different datas also additionaly

Comment: Dude, add it yourself, I can't do everything for you. You asked a question and received a full answer with a working example.